# Bringing back the default context menu in RichEdit when using OLE callback

Tags: c++, contextmenu, richedit

I have a RichEdit control that uses an implementation of the **[IRichEditOleCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774308%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)** interface, so that it can host images and embedded objects.

Part of this interface is the **[GetContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774317%28VS.85%29.aspx)** method. If this method remains unimplemented, the context menu (obviously) will not show up. Returning E_NOTIMPL does not do the trick.

I would not like to implement a context menu from scratch, while the default one is perfectly fine. Is there a simple way to bring back the context menu while using **IRichEditOleCallback**?

EDIT: I discovered that a click on the "context menu" keyboard key still brings up the default menu. It's a right-click that doesn't work.